# How to find optimal solution when simplex tableau in optimal form has negative solutions?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Below is the simplex tableau in optimal format. I supposed to have identity matrix, but instead I got negative values. This means my solutions are negative. How to proceed further in order to find optimal solution to a problem?

[Simplex Tableau in optimal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYAti.png)

Comment: Use arificial variables in order to have an initial solution.

Comment: Do you mean substituting negative variables with positive one? If yes, I know that there is such special case, but I don't know how to implement. Please elaborate.
FYI: The attached table already represents simplex tableau in optimal format. Meaning, I already found basic feasible solution, found entering variable and checked for optimality. I just ended up with basic feasible solutions being negative. This is where I got stuck

Answer (score 0):

The representation of the table seems to confuse you. Here is the ordinary representation of the final tableau:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline y_1 &y_2&y_3&y_4&y_5&\color{red}{y_6}&\color{red}{y_7}&\color{red}{y_8}&s_1&s_2&s_3&\textrm{RHS} \\ \hline 3&1&5&1&2&\color{red}{1}&0&0&-1&0&0&10 \\ \hline -1&-2&1&1 &-1&0&\color{red}{1}&0&0&-1&0&4\\ \hline 2&3&2&1&1&0&0&\color{red}{1}&0&0&-1&7 \\ \hline 25&25&40&90&20&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

The basic variables are $y_6,y_7,y_8$. The optimal solution is $( y_1^*,y_2^*,y_3^*,y_4^*,y_5^*,y_6^*,y_7^*,y_8^*)=(0,0,0,0,0,10,4,7)$.

To reduce the number of columns we can omit the columns of the basic variables and append an extra column at the left side.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline & y_1 &y_2&y_3&y_4&y_5&s_1&s_2&s_3&\textrm{RHS} \\ \hline y_6&3&1&5&1&2&-1&0&0&10 \\ \hline y_7&-1&-2&1&1 &-1&0&-1&0&4\\ \hline y_8&2&3&2&1&1&0&0&-1&7 \\ \hline C&25&25&40&90&20&0&0&0&0\\ \hline \end{array}$$

From this "reduced" table we can read off as well, the basic variables and their corresponding values.